# how to create a simple settings form?

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, application-settings

**My project**

I have a project that allows you to download Internet files as csv, txt, xls, etc, from different sites (stores web sites). These files are purchase orders.

The download process involves download options (parameters) that can be divided into three categories:

- date range: initial date and final date
- order status: available, downloaded, readed, etc.
- store name

**My problem**

I need to create a form like this:

[image]

Settings will be saved in a database so I will not use app.config file.

The main problem is that the download options for each store are not the same. For example, store A uses these orders status and dont need a date range (so, date range control must be hidden)

- status a
- status b

And store B uses theses status and it need a date range

- status c
- status d
- date range

How can I disable options according the selected store?

How can I handle several options in a combo box easly?

Comment: how many stores are there?   Supposing there are just 2:  I would use a combobox populated with the store choices. In the SelectionChanged event, your app could then set the `Visible` property for a panel associated to that particular store, and unset  the `Visible` property holding the settings for the other store.

Answer (score 0):

you can show or hide elements by using

```
 this.button1.Visible = false; //hide
 this.button1.Visible = true; //show
```

i would write a template parser to offer / choose diffrent options (if i understand you correct)